# Angularjs Synced inputs for percetange

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to have **x** amount of text input fields.

Each input field will start off with an equal value to the rest. 
This value is `100 / Number of inputs`.

I need to have the input fields synced, so when one value is changed, the rest of the values are recalculated to equal 100.

This problem seems fairly complex to solve, but I'm sure it must have been done before, it seems like it could be quite common.

Instead of me badly explaining the problem, here is an example of it working. It doesn't use text fields, rather sliders. But the solution is the same.

https://www.humblebundle.com/weekly

Click `Choose where your money goes`

[image]

jsFiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/r4qbx9Lb/5/

Comment: Relevant [UX question for similar problem](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82466/cumulative-percentage-between-4-controls)

Comment: is it necessary that sum of all the input fields be 100?

Comment: The number doesn't necessarily have to be 100, but it always need to be the same.

Comment: means all input fields must have same value, at all times...correct?

Comment: Plz specify exactly what you want - how rest fields should change(i.e decrease by same %)? If you want to copy behavior - first investigate yourself what exactly is going on there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a `$watch` in your controller since you want all your input values to change based on a change in any of them.  In your `$watch` callback function, you need to figure out which array index (what input) had been changed by the user.

All of this would look something like the following:

```
  // 100 in this example, but can be whatever
  $scope.totalValue = 100;

  $scope.$watch('inputs', function(newValue, oldValue){
       for(var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++){
         if(newValue[i].value != oldValue[i].value){
             $scope.changedIndex = i;
             $scope.leftOverValue = $scope.totalValue - newValue[i].value;
             $scope.percentChange = (newValue[i].value - oldValue[i].value) / oldValue[i].value;
             console.log($scope.leftOverValue);
             console.log(percentChange);
         }
     }
  }, true);
```

Once you have this information, you can apply it to all of the array values that weren't changed by the user.  So run another loop (you'll need to split out your two loops because you don't know what index the changed value is initially) and change any of the non-affected index values in this loop:

```
 for(var x = 0; x < newValue.length; x++){
       if($scope.changedIndex != x){
           //Do math and apply logic
       }
 }
```

Then you can apply any math formula you want to adjust your other values.  You'll have to figure this part out - depending on if you want your other values to change proportionally to their old value or proportionally to the change the user made to the input they edited.

http://jsfiddle.net/r4qbx9Lb/10/